# How to Create a Image Field Template

Tags: media

I've made a image field template called

"field--field-image.tpl.php"

This has override the image field.
But how do I get the image to display

```
<img src="<?php print render($item); ?>" alt="..." class="img-rounded">
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, if all you are wanting to accomplish is to add `class="img-rounded"` to the `<img>` tag, you could do this right before you render `$item`:

```
<?php $item['#item']['attributes']['class']='img-rounded'; ?>
```

(Quick and dirty because this assumes no one else somewhere along the line has added or will be adding a class to your image.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `entity_metadata_wrapper` and in your `template.php` use this code :

```
$photo_field = $wrapper->field_IMAGE_FIELD_OF_CONTENTTYPE->value();
$variables['image'] = theme('image_style',
    array(
            'style_name' => 'large',
            'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
            'class' => 'your_class',
        )
);
```

now in your node page `<?php print $image;?>` will work.